# Cast to ObjectID failed for value

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, express

I receive name(String) in my body in array, And i want to convert every array to it's object Id from my Collection.

I want to refer Strings to Schema, And replace it with its ObjectId,

> Here's my Schema :

```
var tagSchema = new Schema({

name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});
```

> Here's What I Do in my api :

```
var tags = req.body.tags;
tags.forEach((item, index) => {
    Tag.findOne({name: item}, (err,result)=> {
      tags[index] = result._id;
    });
 })
```

But in my Console, I get this error :

CastError: Cast to Array failed for value "[ 'tag1', 'tag2' ]" at path "tags"

> Here's When I log tags :

[ 'tag1', 'tag2' ]

What seems to be the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please `console.log(tags)` and show us the result?

Comment: @Sridhar question edited.

Comment: i think you are not getting result.
console err and result inside findOne

Comment: @MonicaGarud result works fine, the error says :
CastError: Cast to Array failed for value "[ 'tag1', 'tag2' ]" at path "tags"

Comment: @HamedJavaheri tags is array of string and you are pushing ObjectId inside it. declare new array for storing objectId

Comment: @MonicaGarud Can you Please Write the code as answer?

Comment: I think the problem in `findOne` because it returns the first item that is matched, so you should use `find` or `count` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tags is a array of string and you are pushing objectId inside it thats why it is giving error CastError: Cast to Array failed for value "[ 'tag1', 'tag2' ]" at path "tags"

there are multiple solution , you can implement as per your requirement.
see the below example.

```
var tags = req.body.tags;
    var tagsObjectId=[];
    tags.forEach((item, index) => {
        Tag.findOne({name: item}, (err,result)=> {
          if(!err){
             tagsObjectId.push(result._id)
          }
        });
     })
```